# Old scifi/martial arts movie about aliens repopulating after Earth is destroyed

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship, b-movies

I´m looking for the name of a live-action movie I saw a long time ago, when I was a kid.

It's probably a sci-fi B or TV movie:

The plot develops aboard an alien spaceship where a group of human couples are transported after the earth is destroyed. Apparently, the alien civilization that holds them is transporting them to their planet where they plan to use them to repopulate.

However, other alien factions seems to be looking to prevent this and has infiltrated the group and is killing them one by one.

The movie has a ton of martial arts fights. Mainly against some sort of android that the group refers to as "The Driver".

Also one of the characters has a shotgun (No idea how he got it on a spaceship but oh well...)